# Cross domain XHR failing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have an API hosted on one domain that has CORS enabled with the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
```

I am able to make a GET or POST request from hackst.com and it works fine. Link: http://hackst.com/#w3SbV

From my backbone app hosted on another domain, GET requests work fine. But when I try to create and save a new model (i.e. make a POST request), it fails with the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501 (Not Implemented) http://projectwhatup.us:5000/api/posts
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://projectwhatup.us:5000/api/posts. Origin http://ayush.projectwhatup.us is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My relevant backbone code:

```
var newPostData = {
    topic : "New Post",
    body : "new body",          
    user_id : 1,
};  

var newPostModel = new Post(newPostData);
this.model.create(newPostModel);
```

I even tried over-riding the `create` method and making a POST request manually like this:

```
create : function(data) {
    console.log('overriden create');

    $.ajax({
        "url" : this.url,
        "async" : true,
        "beforeSend" : function(obj){
            console.log(obj);
        },
        "contentType" : 'application/json',
        //"crossDomain" : true,  // uncommenting this doesnt help either
        "headers" : {

        },
        "dataType" : 'json',
        "type" : 'POST',
        "data" : JSON.stringify(data),
        "error" : function(err){
            console.log('new post creation failed');
            console.log(err);
        },
        "success" : function(resp){
            console.log('new post created');
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });
}
```

Same error.

I tried a stand-alone GET request on JSFiddle as well (http://jsfiddle.net/X9cqh/5/), but that fails even though my backbone app can make the GET request fine.

I'm completely clueless at this point. Any hints, pointers, solutions?

Comment: looking at [hurl.it](http://hurl.it/hurls/1330531e4f6c2b80fe278890b412cb50c3e4857c/432866d6c733527ea02f6436de63cbfac1a9ccc5) HEAD request to your server, it looks like CORS is only enabled for `http://ayush.projectwhatup.us`

Comment: How come the request from hackst.com goes through, though?

Comment: It's because the request is not being made by your web browser. Similar to Hurl.it, when you create a hackst.com request, it is executed by their server on the back end and then displays the results in your web browser.

Comment: CORS enables one webpage to access information on another domain directly inside the browser, for example an ajax request. Outside the browser, anybody can make HTTP requests to any server at any time. For example, you can telnet 80 into projectwhatup.us right now from any computer regardless if they have CORS enabled.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't thought of the fact that hurl and hackst were making the request via the back-end.

Comment: Update: Set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, jsfiddle still fails http://jsfiddle.net/X9cqh/9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server should also reply to the preflight with the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

This is necessary because the content type is application/json, which is outside the acceptable values defined in the CORS spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: We've added `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` as well as `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With` (either-or, not both at the same time) to the server, yet specifying a `content-type` when making the request causes the request to fail.

Comment: What do you mean by "either-or"? You should include all those values in the header.

Comment: ohhh yeah, man! I wasted 2 days with this trouble. Thank you!

Comment: this is working for me, same issue was encountered and answer is working , many thnks

Answer (score 1):

Your sever setup works. JSFiddle apparently does not make the ajax requests, but you can quickly test that it works by entering these four lines into Chrome console or Safari developer console:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://projectwhatup.us:5000/api/posts', false);
xhr.send();
xhr.responseText;
```

[image]

If you try this with a domain that does not allow CORS, it will error out.

Comment: Figured out that that adding `Content-Type: application/json` to the request causes CORS to fail. Without it, the ajax calls are working (http://jsfiddle.net/X9cqh/11/) The problem is when making a POST request, the API needs that header set or it responds with a `400 Bad Request`

Comment: The code in this answer doesn't trigger a preflight (no extra headers and using a simple method GET), which is why it appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that adding a 'Content-Type' header makes your CORS request fail is because your server is set up wrongly.

If the client wishes to specify particular headers or use an unusual http method verb (e.g. PUT), then the browser will first do a 'preflight' OPTIONS call to ensure that it is allowed to set those headers.  Your server needs to respond to this OPTIONS call with the appropriate headers.  You'll see that options call in the network tab of the Chrome developer tools or firebug if you want to confirm that this is what the problem is.

You may be interested in my more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015018/jersey-content-type-customization/13894742#13894742).