# How to get json data from other server in angular using HTTPget correctly?

Tags: angularjs, json, http, http-get

I have access to some database on other server but still I am not being able to get data for this json it shows cors and shows 2 errors
**XHR failed loading: GET**,
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load:CORS**  but I do have access to that server earlier also it showed cors while posting data but there was some code error and not server acceptance problem. This time in getting data is also I guess some code error on my side

```
{
  "emp": [
    {
      "BNK": "Rock",
      "GPIs": [
        "9233333456"
      ]
    },
    {
      "BNK": "Jack",
      "GPIs": [
        "9234343434",
        "9289989898"
        ]
    }
  ],
"status": "ok"
}



 <script>
  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://oher_server_url').success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.dta = data.emp;
    });
  });
</script>

  <table border=1>
                <tr>
                <th>type_BNK</th>
                <th>type_GPIs</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in dta ">
                <td>{{x.BNK}}</td>
                <td>{{x.GPIs}} </td>
  </table>
```

Comment: the `url` you're trying to access is is a different domain that yours and hence being rejected. You'll need to configure the server to allow your domain.

Comment: My domain is allowed on that server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similler problem listed here,

[Cross domain XHR failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464921/cross-domain-xhr-failing)

if you are loading json data, recommend to use `$http.jsonp`

You may also consider writing  http interceptor like this

[XHR Interceptor in an AngularJS web app](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/xhr-interceptor-in-an-angularjs-web-app/)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you didn't enabled cross origin resource sharing on the server so your web page can't access the server, it's a little hard to know for sure if the problem is in the server or at your web page.

you need to check if you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your headers, if you don't, you should enable it, I don't know what technology the server is using but there are lots of guide for difference technologies [here](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).

If the header did exist and accepted your domain it's probably because your browser doesn't support CORS, you can check if the browser you are using at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors).

Comment: CORS is enabled on server and Browser also supports CORS