# Not getting any response with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a simple script to insert data to database using ajax and jquery . It seems that I am not receiving back any response , and I don't think I am doing something wrong . So , can anybody take a look and help me ?

process.php

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $user= $_POST['username'];
    $password  = $_POST['password'];

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','car_rental');

    $query = 'insert into car_admin (admin_id,admin_username,admin_password) values(?,?,?)';
    $query = $con->prepare($query);
    $query-> bind_param('iss',$id,$user,$password);

    if($query->execute()) { echo "done";}
    else { echo "failed"; }

    $query->close();
    $con->close();

?>
```

register.php

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<form id="register" method="POST" >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Register 
        </legend>
        ID: <input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="" />
    Username : <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" />
    Passsword : <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <input id="submit"  type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />

    </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {

         var id = $('#id').val();
         var username = $('#username').val();
         var password = $('#password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'process.php',
            data:'id='+id+'username='+username+'password='+password,
            success:function(data){
               $('#result').html(data);

        }

    }); 
});
```

Comment: You can be doing more to debug this. Look at the developer console. Is your ajax request correct? Do you get a response? What does it look like? You can see it all *right there*. That will narrow down where to look *considerably*.

Comment: telling me xhr failed What does that mean

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464921/cross-domain-xhr-failing

Comment: I am using a local host and all scripts are in the same folder

Comment: is there an error in your web console?

Comment: Nooo just xhr failed

Comment: This `data:'id='+id+'username='+username+'password='+password,` should be seperated by comma

Comment: From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085649/ajax-multiple-data)  `data: {status: status, name: name},`

Comment: The process page worked and values are added to database but no response xhr failed load,,,,

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). First update your title.

Comment: Am betting page is reloading because you aren't preventing default form submit

Comment: how to do that??

Comment: I did this it worked thankyou !!!  event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

**Prevent the form from submitting via the browser**

**You need to change your code to include the correct formatting**
    data:'id='+id+'&username='+username+'&password='+password,

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<form id="register" >
<fieldset>
<legend>
Register
</legend>
ID: <input id="id" type="text" name="id" value="" />
Username : <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" />
Passsword : <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="" />
<button id="submit"  name="submit"  />Register</button>

</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser
var id = $('#id').val();
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'login.php',
data:'id='+id+'&username='+username+'&password='+password,
success:function(data){

  $('#result').html(data);

}

});



});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to escape data you for use in the URL.  Better yet, just pass an object and let jQuery do it for you.

Comment: You also should be handling form submit, not waiting on a button click.  Not everyone submits forms with buttons... some of us like to push enter.  Some people use alternative input devices.

Comment: @Brad  i just tried to add few lines to sort out this problem..but thanku brad for this usefull comment

Answer (score -1):

The reason your ajax is failing is because you are not posting the parameters correctly. If ID is 1, username is "Username", and password is "password", the following code will return the value shown.

```
'id='+id+'username='+username+'password='+password,
id=1username=Usernamepassword=Password
```

You need to change your code to include the correct formatting, as per below.

```
'id='+id+'&username='+username+'&password='+password,
```

Then your Ajax request should work. I can see no problems with your PHP. I would also suggest doing an **encodeURIComponent** as if your strings contain any URI characters, it will cause further problems. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery) as it is an excellent example of making an Ajax request.

Comment: I made them like this { ex:ex}, but still xhr failed

Comment: You ought to escape those values properly. I think `encodeURIComponent` will do what you want.

Comment: @Tom Yes, I have given reference to that in my answer.
@MoudiNasrallah I see you have managed to resolve this by preventing the default action of the submit button. So now you are getting back the response you expect, and it is being passed to your .success() function? I would encourage you to also have a .fail function, as described here:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR
Also, the method you have described `{ ex:ex}`, I believe is a much better way as jQuery should automatically do the uri encoding for you. And

Comment: Thankyou I will !